# Move code to DLL out of Windows Store app if it uses full-framework library?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, portable-class-library, class-library

I've created Windows Store application on .Net 4.5, that uses AngleSharp 0.8.5, HTML parser engine. My project contains many code files which i gonna use in another application, so i decided to move that code into PCL library, to separate project.

But i cannot add AngleSharp DLL from NuGet system to my PCL project, as it says:

> Could not install package 'AngleSharp 0.8.5'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-win+net45+sl40+wp', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I've tried to add AngleSharp DLL manually to project, but if i try to build my PCL project i get warnings like this:

> Warning   2   The primary reference "AngleSharp" could not be resolved
>   because it was built against the
>   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259" framework. This is a
>   higher version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile4". prototypeLibrary

And this

> The primary reference "AngleSharp" could not be resolved
>   because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly
>   "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile4". To resolve this problem,
>   either remove the reference "AngleSharp" or retarget your application
>   to a framework version which contains "System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". prototypeLibrary

**I also tried to create a normal Class Library project and move my code there, but i cannot add a reference to it from my Windows Store application.**

What should i do if i need to move some code out of Windows Store executable and re-use, in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *Warning 2* you have created a Profile **4** PCL library, which is considered a legacy profile that is not supported in VS 2013 and later. Profile 4 targets .NET 4.5, Silverlight 4, Windows 8 and Windows Phone 7. *AngleSharp* is incompatible with both SL4 and WP7, so this PCL profile is not a viable option.

For maximum compatibility with *AngleSharp*, I recommend that you switch to PCL profile 259, which targets:

- .NET 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8
- Xamarin Android
- Xamarin iOS Classic and Unified APIs

If you switch to this PCL profile, you should have no problem referencing your portable class library from your Windows Store application.